# How do I customize Google Map Marker Icon?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I can't figure out how to change marker icon of Google Map.
Here's my code. Most of marker is already shown. I'd like to change only my current location.

Controller

```
  def restaurant_nearby
        @restaurants = Restaurant.near(params[:lat], params[:lng], params[:num], params[:lang])
        @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@restaurants.to_hash) do |r, marker|
                        marker.lat r["lat"]
                        marker.lng r["lng"]
                        marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: "area/infowindow", locals: { place: r })
                        marker.json({title: r["restaurantname"]})
        end

        @hash_current_pos = {
                        lat: params[:lat],
                        lng: params[:lng],
                        icon: '/here.png',
                        infowindow: render_to_string(partial: "area/infowindow_current_pos"),
                        title: "You are here"
        }

        @hash = @hash.push(@hash_current_pos)

        content = render_to_string(:partial => 'area/restaurant_map', locals: {hash: @hash})
        render json: {html: content}, status: :ok
  end
```

Here's script of view.
area/_restaurant_map.html.slim

```
javascript:
  jQuery(function(){

       mapStyle = [[{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-35"}]}]];

      handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
      handler.buildMap({ provider: {styles: mapStyle}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers( #{raw hash.to_json});
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      handler.getMap().setZoom(15);
      });
 });

/! Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements
/[if lt IE 9]
  = javascript_include_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"
```

I'd appreciate any of advice.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I worked out. Like this.

```
@hash_current_pos = {
                        lat: params[:lat],
                        lng: params[:lng],
                        picture: {url: '/here.png', width: 140, height: 180},
                        infowindow: render_to_string(partial: "area/infowindow_current_pos"),
                        title: "You are here"
        }
```

Appreciated all contributes!

Answer (score -1):

If you just wanted to customise Google's icon, you can set a `size` and `color`

Otherwise, `markers=icon:URLofIcon|markerLocation`

`URLofIcon` being the URL of the icon you would like to use, which should be URL encoded (using a shortening service which will probably URL encode it for you and make the code look much nicer)

Comment: Your answer should be better specified, i.e. where put the solution, some code samples..